# How to get value from another class's function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Like

```
class A {
   public var tip : String = ""
}

class B {
   val tip2 = A().tip
   println(tip2)
}

class C {
   tiper("abc")
   tiper("def")
   tiper("ghi")

   fun tiper(txt) {
      A().tip = txt
      B.showTip()
   }
}
```

To be brief, I have a class B, which outputs a 'tip'. There is class C, which creates the text for the 'tip'. And I need to send a value from class C to class B. I tried doing it through class A, sending the value there and then reading it in class B to display it.
But in this case it just displays the value "", i.e. by default from class A.
Why isn't the value passed by class C taken instead?

The above code is greatly simplified and is a hypothetical description of what I actually have in my code. This is just an abstract example.

I'm a terrible Kotlin programmer, I was just asked to do this one job, so I don't know much about it, hope for your help.

Comment: hi, the code you've provided [doesn't compile](https://pl.kotl.in/SCCINQ41I) - can you update it? Also, it's not clear why you need these classes, it looks like you're asking how to solve a workaround, not the actual task at hand ([X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). My guess is storing values in a `Map<String, String>` might be what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new object from type `A` every time you call it's constructor `A()`.

Thus, inside `tiper`, you're creating an object of type `A` and setting the `tip` value on that object instance.

Then however, you create an object of type `B` which creates a *new* object of type `A` internally. This has no link to the first object of type `A` you've created. Thus, it does not contain the value you wanted to set but rather the default you've set, which is the empty string `""`.

---

Keeping close to our example, you can instead adjust the value on the object of type `A` that is embedded in the object of type `B`.

```kotlin
class A {
    var tip: String = ""
}

class B() {
    
    val tipHolder = A()

    fun showTip() {
        println(tipHolder.tip)
    }
}

fun tiper(txt: String) {
    val tipPrinter = B()
    tipPrinter.tipHolder.tip = txt

    tipPrinter.showTip()
}

fun main() {
    tiper("abc")
    tiper("def")
    tiper("ghi")
}
```

However, without more details on the actual problem, it's hard to help you with the underlying problem you're trying to solve, as written by @aSemy in the comment section.

Comment: thank u so much. didn't even think about that simple solution